# Ошибка NaN при смене видео

Tags: javascript, видео

День добрый! как мне корректно сменить видео по событию onended? Вот код...

это процесс заполнения progress, во время воспроизведения 1-ого видео заполняется корректно.

```
function updateProgressBar() {
let percentage = Math.floor((100 /video.duration) * video.currentTime);
scrollVideo.value = percentage;}
```

В конце воспроизведения по событию onended, я выбираю видео следующее для просмотра и сеняю аттрибут src у video

```
  scrollVideo.value = 0;
    percentage = 0;
    video.pause();
    video.removeAttribute('src');
    video.src = arrayVideo[i].linkFilm;
    video.poster = arrayVideo[i].poster;
    video.play();
    document.querySelector('div.cntEndVideo').remove();
```

В итоге сыпется ошибка NaN, и progress не заполняется. Перемотка работает..

Comment: Проверяйте переменные, которые в формуле рассчета. Что то из этого не число, вот и получаете NaN

Comment: формула нормальная, при воспроизведении 1-ого видео. Прогресс заполняется корректно, NaN возникает когда в конце проигрывания из предложенных выбираю другое видео и меняю его в теге video у аттрибута src. Поймать надо как-то когда видео загружается. Продолжительность видео показывает а вот шкала не заполняется прогресса просмотра

Comment: Разобрался сам вообщем! Если при смене видео влетает в функцию NaN, то модуль Math почему-отваливается убрал его и оставил только математическую формулу всё заработало